# Karma Jasmine Angular not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am trying to learn how to use angular and karma to test angularjs and nodejs. I have used Noesavy's youtube videos to learn how to set up karma and jasmine. His examples work fine but when I try to use jasmine and karma with my own code I get angular undefined. My code is posted below:

passwordScript.js

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('S',
['$scope',
function($scope){

$scope.checkPass = function(insert_password, confirm_password){

    if(insert_password == confirm_password){
        $scope.passBoole = true;
    } else {
        $scope.passBoole = false;
    }
};


}]);
```

checkPassSpec

```
describe("Password Controller", function(){
    var $rootScope,
        $scope,
        controller;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('myApp');

        inject(function($injector){
            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $injector.get('$controller')("S", {$scope: $scope});
        });
    });

describe('Password check', function(){
    it('should set $scope.passBoole top false', function(){
        checkPass("bob", "tom");
        expect($scope.passBoole).toEqual(false);
    })
    it('should set scope.passBoole to true', function(){
    checkPass("bob", "bob");
    expect($scope.passBoole).toEqual(true);
    });
 });

});
```

karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Dec 11 2014 17:07:06 GMT+0000 (GMT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
'./bower_components/angular/angular.js',
'./bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
'./bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
    'app/**/*.js',
    'test/**/*.js'
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false
  });
};
```

I really have no idea why this is happening and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Silly idea, but are you sure the path to angular.js specified in karma.conf.js is correct? (If you check in the browser running Karma, can you find it in the sources panel of the development console?)

Comment: Could you try removing the dots `'/bower_components/angular/angular.js'`?

Comment: You should also change the logLevel to `logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG` to get a more verbose output and find out where does the problem come from

Answer (score 4):

```
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'app/**/*.js',
  'spec/**/*.js'
],
```

I know this is a late answer, but I had the same problem and removing the './' solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Please replace content of files:[] block inside karma.config.js with following

```
files: [
'/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
'/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
'/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
'app/**/*.js',
'test/**/*.js'
],
```